# TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined discord.js command handler

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Okay So I am getting an error this worked Just Yesterday and out of nowhere it broke.....

Now here is the error

```
/app/handlers/command.js:8
            bot.commands.set(pull.config.name, pull);
                                         ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
at load (/app/handlers/command.js:8:42)
at /app/handlers/command.js:12:75
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at module.exports (/app/handlers/command.js:12:62)
at /app/index.js:16:72
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at Object.<anonymous> (/app/index.js:16:33)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:759:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:770:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:628:32)
```

Each Command open up with

```
module.exports = {
config: {
name: "command name"
```

Now here is the code in the command handler

```
const { readdirSync } = require("fs")

module.exports = (bot) => {
    const load = dirs => {
        const commands = readdirSync(`./commands/${dirs}/`).filter(d => d.endsWith('.js'));
        for (let file of commands) {
            let pull = require(`../commands/${dirs}/${file}`);
            bot.commands.set(pull.config.name, pull);
            if (pull.config.aliases) pull.config.aliases.forEach(a => bot.aliases.set(a, pull.config.name));
          };
        };
        ["currency", "fun", "holiday", "info", "moderation"].forEach(x => load(x));
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay The error was my project did not save for some reason so I messed up evrything is fine but I just have to get everything to save again.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like maybe you didn't define the name variable, try defining it just before the code, since its returning undefined in the error.